# how to display values on labels from plist. objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

i have the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Daniel</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Bad boy</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Mary</string>
    <key>description</key>
    <string>Good girl</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

i want to display on my label's values name and description depending of name:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropList"   ofType:@"plist"];
ComplexArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (int i = 0; i < [ComplexArray count]; i++) {
            ThirdViewController *item = [ComplexArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([item.name isEqualToString: @"Mary"]) { 
        _nameLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        _descriptionLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"description"];
    }  
}
```

And why i can't do like this (i did this when i have no plist, but now this return errors):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropList" ofType:@"plist"];
ComplexArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (int i = 0; i < [ComplexArray count]; i++) {
ThirdViewController *item = [ComplexArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
if ([item.name isEqualToString: @"Mary"]) { 
_nameLabel.text=item.name;
_descriptionLabel.text=item.description;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, you pretty much had it right already.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropList" ofType:@"plist"];
ComplexArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSDictionary *dict in ComplexArray) {
    if ([dict[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Mary"]) {
        _nameLabel.text = dict[@"name"];
        _descriptionLabel.text = dict[@"description"];
        break;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code it Must work perfect !

```
       // Read plist from bundle and get Root Dictionary out of it
    NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropList" ofType:@"plist"]];

    // Your dictionary contains an array of dictionary
    // Now pull an Array out of it.
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"keyarray"];


    // Now a loop through Array to fetch single Item 

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {



if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Mary"])
{
    // Do stuff...

        NSString *name= [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *description= [dict objectForKey:@"Description"];

}

    }
```

you need to add a key befor the array .

```
<key>keyarray</key>
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i display only name and description depending of name (for example Mary)?

Comment: That code won't work.  Why would you call `[NSArray initWithContentsOfFile:]` passing it a dictionary?  It should be a string.  However you've already loaded the `.plist` file?!?  Very far from "Must work perfect"...

Comment: i have an error: incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDictionary *' to parameter of type 'NSString * _Nonull'

Comment: @droppy , yeah you are right i suggest to add a key for array then get the array from the NSDictionary  .

Answer (score 0):

Perform following steps:

1. Get the plist data in a dictionary

   ```
   NSString *plistPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NameOfPlistFile" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSDictionary *bundleDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
   ```
2. Get the Value with respect to Key

   ```
   NSString *nameString = [bundleDictionary valueForKey:kCustomURLScheme];
   ```

Hope this helps!